# IF Custom field value equals ZERO

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, post-meta, variables, meta-value

I am trying to use the following code to check for my custom field for a value of ZERO to then display my div

```
<?php 
$mp_price_sort = get_post_meta('mp_product_price');
if ($mp_price_sort  == '0') { ?>
    <div><?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcodes]'.$mp_buy_button.'[/shortcodes]'); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

However it is interperting as a value of anything, thus displaying the div, but I need it to check for the number 0. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure `mp_product_price` is set? Try `var_dump($mp_price_sort);`

Comment: How do I use var_dump? Im not familiar. I used the_meta to display values and mp_price_sort is 0 for free products and for other products it is whatever the price is. So I am trying to check for the free products which has a value of 0

Comment: I get what you are doing, I'm try to establish if $mp_price_sort actually has any value at all. `$mp_price_sort = get_post_meta('mp_product_price'); var_dump($mp_price_sort);`

Comment: Ok I used your suggestion and this is what it gives me - bool(false) - which is weird cause it was on a page that has a price of 25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using get_post_meta incorrectly, so it is returning FALSE every time. As PHP equates '0' and FALSE, your div will always be displayed.

The correct syntax for get_post_meta is:

```
<?php $meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single); ?>
```

where $post_id is the only required argument.

Comment: Oh Ok, THANKS! I've used your suggestion and change a few things and now it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used -

```
<?php 
$mp_price_sort = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mp_price_sort', true);
if ($mp_price_sort == 0) { ?>
    <div>TESTING</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This answer is redundant. @vancoder 's post contains the necessary information and is the correct solution.